# My button on clicked is not working in Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am facing a problem which is my button ID is well-configured and in my main activity, I am calling the button using the correct ID too, but after I run the project on the emulator, the button is not working after I clicked on it for multiple times.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Mobile Quiz Application"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Welcome To The Quiz App!"
                android:textColor="@color/txtTitle"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Please enter your name before starting the quiz."
                android:textColor="@color/txtDesc"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Your name......"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:textColor="@color/txtTitle"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/txtDesc" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Start"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="Continue"
                android:textStyle="bold">
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my main file:

```
package com.example.quizapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btnStart = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_Start)
        val nameInput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etName)
        btnStart.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "You clicked me.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you further describe what do you mean by *the button is not working after I clicked on it for multiple times*?

Comment: I have checked your code and everything works fine. Toast is displayed after button click.

Comment: I wan to show a toast after i clicked on the button. But i have clicked on it for many times but it doesn't show the toast.

Comment: @bongo do you mean you have tried to run my code and test the toast is workable??

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with your code. Try to delete your App and reinstall it again? Or restarting your emulator?

Comment: @HowardTeh yes, I used activity code and layout and i see the toast

Comment: Alright I have re-installed my emulator and it now works. It's weird tho. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

findViewById is an old method.
i would recommend you to use with ViewBinding.
[click here to documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: This is not an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use viewBinding

add line to **build.gradle**

```
  buildFeatures{
    viewBinding true
}
```

and update your activity like this

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.btnStart.setOnClickListener{
      Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "You clicked me.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```